# How do I configure a Cart Rule for Free Shipping in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento-2.1.7, free-shipping

I'm using Magento 2.1.7.

Trying to figure out a simple Cart Rule for Free Shipping using a Specific coupon code:

```
Specific Code
No conditions
Actions:
 Apply - Fixed amount discount for whole cart
 Apply to Shipping Amount: Yes
 Free shipping: For shipment with matching items
```

I've tried a few other configuration combinations, but nothing seems to be working.

If I turn on the Free Shipping shipping method, Free shipping is applied, but if it's off, and the rule is applied, there is no free shipping option. I've also tried enabling the Free Shipping setting within the carrier, but the coupon code does not enable that either.

I've read that there are some bugs regarding free shipping cart rules:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8614

but was curious if anyone had any luck getting it working.

Comment: I think you'll have to use some conditions, otherwise it wouldn't select any products eligible for the rule. Even a cover all condition "subtotal is => $0"

Comment: thx @dawhoo - I added a condition that the cart must have 1 or more products, still not working

Answer (score 2):

Try the following steps:

1. Set Apply to “Percent of product price discount.
2. Set Apply to Shipping Amount to “Yes.”
3. Set Free Shipping to “For shipment with matching items.”

For more details, go through https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-free-shipping.html

**UPDATE**
You will not see any Free shipping option in the cart, rather when you select any shipping option, Magento automatically substracts that shipping cost. Suppose I have two shipping option available to select in cart Table Rate and Flat Rate having cost 10 and 8 respectively. Now, suppose the user has chosen Flat Rate, now you will see in the total's section that the actual shipping cost that is 8 is now added in the cart total. This is how the rule works.

Comment: Thanks @anshu - I've tried that, no luck. Also, if I enable Free Shipping per the instructions in the link, it is always visible (regardless of the minimum amount set)

Comment: @NathanBennett You will not see any Free shipping option in the cart, rather when you select any shipping option, Magento automatically substracts that shipping cost. Suppose I have two shipping option available to select in cart Table Rate and Flat Rate having cost 10 and 8 respectively. Now, suppose the user has chosen Flat Rate, now you will see in the total's section that the actual shipping cost that is 8 is now added in the cart total. This is how the rule works.

Comment: @NathanBennett Please share the screen-shot for the rule.